# Get count(tweet) for my all follower in twitter using java api

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I m java developer and i know some of twitter api components as below

1. twitter4j-2.2.2.jar
2. jtwitter.jar

Get count(tweet) for my all follower in twitter using java api

do you have any idea about it and get it better way implementation ?

pankaj

Answer (score 0):

1. List all followers (`twitter.getFollowersIDs(..)`)
2. For each user use `twitter.showUser(id)` and then sum their tweet counts (`user.getStatusesCount()`)

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but one more question in my mind ..is it possible to get all public twitter users's tweet count ..?

Comment: I don't think so. You can always try to traverse the graph (get each user his followers, their followers, and so on). But the API has its limitations

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.....You can find count of any public twitter user's tweet by using below twitter api...

https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterapi&include_entities=true

which returns a JSON object. You then parse that with your favorite JSON parser, and extract the "statuses_count" field...:)